# While deleting a player record system throws object reference error in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my `Xamarin Forms` app, I am trying to delete a player by clicking on a button in the `Home` screen, but this is throwing a "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at this point: `var playerDetails = (sender as MenuItem).CommandParameter as PlayerDetails;` How can I delete a player record based on an `id` ? I am not sure how to create a delete query in SQLite/Xamarin Forms.

PlayerDetails class:

```cs
    public class PlayerDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string FullName { get; set; }
    ......

    }
```

SQlite connection are Instatiated in the Home class:

```cs
    public Home()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                conn = DependencyService.Get<Isqlite>().GetConnection();
                conn.CreateTable<PlayerDetails>();
                players = new ObservableCollection<PlayerDetails>();
                collectionview.ItemsSource = players;
                DisplayDetails();
            }
```

Delete operation during on click on the Remove Player button in Home screen.

```cs
     public async void DeleteButton_OnClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
                {
                    bool res = await DisplayAlert("Message", "Do you want to delete a player ?", "Ok", "Cancel");

                    if(res)
                    {
                        var playerDetails = (sender as MenuItem).CommandParameter as PlayerDetails;
                        players.Remove(playerDetails);
                        conn.Delete(playerDetails);
                    }
                }
```

Home.xaml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
                 x:Class="soccerapp.Home" BackgroundColor="White" Title="Home">
        <ContentPage.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="playerTemplate">
                <ContentView>
                    <StackLayout  Margin="5,5" BackgroundColor="LightGreen">
                        <Label Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Mobile}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding SoccerPosition}"/>
                        <Button Text="Remove Player"  Clicked="DeleteButton_OnClicked" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50"  TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="OrangeRed"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>

                </ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout Margin="5">
            <CollectionView x:Name="collectionview"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource playerTemplate}">
                <!--span here decides the number of items shows in one line. Now is 3 items one line-->
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="3" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: How is your ViewModel/View(Xaml) defined?

Comment: Added my  `Home.xaml` to the question

Comment: @SushiHangover I have updated my Home.xaml in the question

Comment: I would advise you to debug and put a breakpoint and see what is happening. `sender` should be the `Button` that called the `DeleteButton_OnClicked`, and a `Button` is not a `MenuItem`. Easiest fix here would be `car playerDetails = (sender as Button).BindingContext as PlayerDetails`. That being said a cleaner way would be to remove the eventhandler and rework this to use a `Command` and `CommandParameter`. To add you've never set the `CommandParameter` so even if the cast was valid the `CommandParameter` would be null.

Comment: That really helped me, removing a player is working now. One question in between, is that actually removing data from SQlite database table, because we haven't provide our query with player id..so how does it work ?

Comment: the [PrimaryKey] attribute tells sqlite which property is the PK